# Checking for the password script not working - please check my code for errors

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time using StackOverflow to type a question, can anyone check my code and tell me what seems to be wrong, I wanted to check if the password is written correct or wrong,

when I run that script in the terminal, it displays the "Enter your password" line but when I type in the password, whether it's correct or not, it doesn't do anything and the script ends without displaying any messages from the two messages I put in the if statement, I hope I described the problem well...

```
password_file = open('SecretPasswordFile.txt')
secret_password = password_file.read()
result = ""
typed_password = input("Enter your Password!: ")

if typed_password == secret_password:
    result += "Access granted!"
    if typed_password == "12345":
        result += "That password is one that an idiot puts on their luggage!!!"
else:
    print('Access Denied!!')
print(result)
```

Comment: Will u please describe your problem more precisely ?

Comment: When I run this code in the terminal, the program starts with "Enter your Password:" line but when I do so "enter the password", whether the case that I'm entering correct pass or wrong pass, it doesn't evaluate my password as it should do , and the program ends without displaying Access granted or Access Denied.

Comment: The typical reason for this is that the `SecretPasswordFile.txt` contains a newline character, so `secret_password = 'abc\n'` or some such.  That would never match the value from `input` because `input` never returns the newline.  Provide the exact contents of `SecretPasswordFile.txt`.

Comment: But can't I do something in the txt to fix that?? because I want to used the txt for evaluating the password????

Comment: And now I tried replacing the content of secret_password with the actual correct password but it gave me Access Denied

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the problem i have understood yet

1. Line `if typed_password == "12345":` will not work unless user enter correct password

   Fix: add it in [elif](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm) statement
2. If `result` is to show desired message like `Access Granted` or `Access Denied!!` or `That password is one that an idiot puts on their luggage!!!`

   Fix: Use `print()` function

### Fixed Code

```
password_file = open('SecretPasswordFile.txt')
secret_password = password_file.read().rstrip() # fix : added rstrip() to trim whitespaces from the right side
typed_password = input("Enter your Password!: ")

if typed_password == secret_password:
    print ("Access granted!")
elif typed_password == "12345":
     print("That password is one that an idiot puts on their luggage!!!")
else:
    print('Access Denied!!')
```

Comment: I tried that now but when I checked the pass again, and I wrote it correctly, it said Access Denied!!

Comment: files generally end up with a new line character, which might be causing the password mismatch.

Comment: Are you using new line character ?

Comment: Thanks all for helping, it finally worked, I didn't see the { .rstrip() } the first time, when I wrote it, the script worked perfectly fine, Thank you so much @TeraByte...